# Error when downloading Apple Pass in Chrome for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Issue with downloading Apple Pass on an iPhone device using Chrome and Firefox. It works fine on Safari. On Chrome for iOS it says:

`Sorry, your Pass cannot be installed to Passbook at this time`.

For Firefox it says:

`Failed to Add Pass An error occurred while adding the pass to Wallet. Please try again later.`

I tried just downloading the Apple Pass from a desktop browser and it downloads and I can install it fine on an iPhone/simulator which I'm assuming is not a problem with the pass itself but maybe rather something I'm missing in the response.

Here is the code I'm using to return the Apple Pass.

```cs
private void ReturnResponse(byte[] applePass)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Formate("attachment; filename={0}", "sample.pkpass"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.apple.pkpass"
    Response.BinaryWrite(applePass);
    Response.End();
}
```

Expected result:

Apple Pass opens and allows the user to add it to their Apple Wallet.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is question is over a year and a half old, but this is still an issue as of March 2021. After a *lot* of trial and error we managed to get it working on Chrome & Firefox. Our specific issue was that the request has to be a GET, and we had a form before the Pass was downloaded that submitted as a POST. Once we change the form to submit a GET the issue was resolved.

We tried to keep the POST and return a 201, which feels correct, but the issue persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Changing our request method from a POST to a GET when serving the pkpass made it possible to download the pass using Google Chrome for Mobile on an iOS device.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something but, to me, this looks like you're jus saying that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66421836/10871073) worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I have found this link which I feel might be related:

https://github.com/eymengunay/php-passbook/issues/73

It says that the anchor you using to link to the pass should contain the this attribute:

target="_system"

I have not tested this resolution myself.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought 20 access passes from a website. The site had the option to "add to apple wallet". It worked fine for 19 of them and then on the very last one I got this same error.

I did not do anything different when trying to add the 20th one.

Wondering if there is a limitation with the number of passes you can add?... but why would it be limited to a random number like 19?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31875010)